# Elasticsearch script filter on object array

Tags: arrays, elasticsearch

I've got a following elasticsearch document:

```
{
"json":{
  "freeSlots":[
         {
            "day":"2015-04-21",
            "beginTime":"08:00:00",
            "endTime":"09:00:00"
         },
         {
            "day":"2015-04-21",
            "beginTime":"14:00:00",
            "endTime":"17:00:00"
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

and I expected that this kind of query would return it:

```
{
"query" : {
    "filtered" : {
        "query" : {
            "match_all" : {}
        }
     },
     "filter" : {
         "script": {
             "script" : "doc['json.freeSlots.endTime'].value - doc['json.freeSlots.beginTime'].value > param1",
             "params" : {
                 "param1" : 7200000
             }
          }
     }
 }
```

Unfortunately it considers only first element of array and its difference between `endTime` and `beginTime` is less than 7200000 ms. How can I change this query so that it returns any document containing an object within `freeSlots` array which duration (difference between `endTime` and `beginTime`) is greater than 7200000 ms? Date mappings are set.

Answer (score 0):

I'd index each slot as a separate document:

     `{
        "day":...
        "beginTime":...
        "endTime":...
     }`

Then use this query:

`{
    "query": {
        "filter": {
            "script": {
                "params": {
                    "delta": 7200000
                },
                "script": "(doc['endTime'].value - doc['beginTime'].value) > delta"
            }
        },
        "filtered": {
            "query": {
                "match_all": {}
            }
        }
    }
}`

Also, you may need to configure the script in the server (AFAIK recent versions don't suppport this kind of dynamic script).

One way of debugging what's going on is to use a `script_field` to output some values:

`...
"script_fields": {
    "delta": {
        "file": "debug_script_fields",
        "lang": "groovy"
    }
}
...`

In the server, in `config/scripts` add a file `debug_script_fields.groovy`:

`doc['endTime'].value - doc['beginTime'].value`

If the value is not what you expect it's unlikely that the filtered query will work.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but I've decided to change my documents and insert a duration field, which is a difference between endTime and beginTime. Now I can query ES using range filter on duration field and everything seems to work, ES takes into account all values present in an array.